# Input function ends prematurely in python when using multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have some code that goes like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def foo():
    while True:
        f=input('Input: ')
        print('Why doesn't this print?')

if __name__=='__main__':    
    p1 = Process(target=bruh)
    print('this prints')
    p1.start()
    print('and so does this')
```

But when ran, I recieve this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\(myUsername)\Desktop\program.py", line 739, in foo
    f=input('still running')

EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

I belive this is because the process ended when it reached the input function, causing it to give an end of field error, but I don't know. Please Help!

(using python 3.8.3)

Answer (score 0):

EOF errors usually are caused by mistakes at the end of the line, like a missing parenthesis or something similar. Try indenting the if into the loop inside the function.

If that doesn't work, maybe you wrote `print('Why doesn't this print?')` instead of `print("Why doesn't this print?")`

Comment: The ``EOFError`` is something different from e.g. ``SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal``.

Answer (score 0):

You have a single quote `'` here: `doesn't`

```
print('Why doesn't this print?')
```

Try to escape it by `\'`, or try without it first:

```
print('Why does this not print?')
```

Double quotes also could be a solution in this case.

In my case PyCharm interprets this error as `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` and highlights a `t` in `doesn't` as an `Unresolved reference` expecting `,` or `)`.

So maybe the issue is not in the provided piece of code, but somewhere else. Look at lines displayed in errors. Maybe you've forget to close some single quote `'` somewhere else

Comment: While the question makes this mistake, the error shown indicates that is not the problem in the actual code. Incorrect literals produce ``SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal``, not an ``EOFError``.